# Extract value from xpath array

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following which prints `100` - which is correct - however, I have to use `print_r()` which is obviously wrong

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<span class="foo" id="bar" itemprop="price">100</span>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$results = $xpath->evaluate('number(//*[@itemprop="price"])');

print_r($results);`
```

So, how should I get the single result which is 100? I've tried `$results[0]` which didn't work.

Am sure it's simple but beating me!

Comment: You don't need to use `print_r()`, I ran your code just fine with `echo` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `->item()` method on the result to access the DOM nodes that your XPath query returns. Also you should rather use the `query()` method when you want to run an XPath query. I've never really understood the purpose of using `evaluate()`.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$results = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop="price"]');

echo $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

**[DOMXPath->query()](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)** returns an instance of `DOMNodeList` which you can iterate on with `foreach()` or access a specific result item by using the `->item()` method. Its only argument is the 0-based index into the returned list.